# the error when I print log in directives - method "splice" is not defined

Tags: vue.js

```
directives: {
 focus (el, { value }, { context }) {
  if (value) {
    context.$nextTick(() => {
      el.focus()
    })
   }
 }
```

},

here is the code of vuex's demo - todoMVC

I know the $nextTick is the method of VueComponent

then I print the log of context

```
directives: {
 focus (el, { value }, { context }) {
   if (value) {
     console.log(context)
     context.$nextTick(() => {
       el.focus()
     })
   }
 }
```

},

finally

```
vue.runtime.esm.js:430 [Vue warn]: Property or method "splice" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.
```

I know that content belong to Vnode
I don't know why there is a mistake, the Vonde didn`t render? if so, how can $nextTick be bind to context?

Comment: I can't reproduce it: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/63t082p2/67/ Show your element where and how you put this directive.

Comment: From the error it looks like your problem is with some other part of the code. Are you sure that this directive is the problem?